# Invisible Recaptcha Challenge popup disappears on parent click

Tags: javascript, popup, invisible-recaptcha

I've implemented the google invisible recaptcha on our website, the captcha works fine, but when the recaptcha popup becomes visible and i click on the parentwindow of the popup (not in the challence popup), the popup goes away and the register account procedure is locked.

I can't find a hook function to inform that my captcha is gone!

Anyone? Thx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i just made parent area unclickable with css property `pointer-event: none`.
You must find generated recaptcha's div with js and set this style